# can someone guide me building a tensorflow model for colour classification on RGB colours

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

i am trying to build a tensorflow model using kears for colour classifier but i am having difficulties in building .if some one can provide any sourses relateed to it or guide me it will be great.thanks in adavanced

Comment: What's your input like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: sir i have only built object and dogvscat classifier using tesnsorflow and keras,and converting input into grayscale images and later calssify it. I am not getting results related to Colour Classification using tensorflow on google aslo